# Unable to toggle fontawesome color

Tags: jquery, css, font-awesome

I am not able to toggle the color of fontawesome icon on clicking it.

```
 <a id="thumbsup">@Html.FontAwesome(FontAwesomeIconSet.ThumbsUp, FontAwesomeStyles.Large2x)</a>
```

When the icon is loaded, I want that to be gray. When clicked, it should be blue. When clicked again, it should be back to gray. (the icon itself is black in color). Can we not toggle between two colors on a fontawesome icon otherthan its original color?

When I try to toggle between the original black color and blue by using toggleclass, it works fine.

```
 //jquery
 $("#thumbsup").toggleclass("bluecolor");
 //css
 .bluecolor{
 color:#0026ff;
 }
```

But if I try to make it gray initially, by adding a class to html, it loads as gray but not toggling to blue when using jquery.

```
//html
<a id="thumbsup" class="graycolor">@Html.FontAwesome(FontAwesomeIconSet.ThumbsUp, FontAwesomeStyles.Large2x)</a>
//css
.graycolor{
color:#999;
 }
//jquery
$("#thumbsup").toggleclass("bluecolor");
```

When I apply the above logic on a plain text, it is toggling perfectly.Is it not working as fontawesome itself is loaded as class? Is there an alternate way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify both classes in toggleClass:

```
$("#thumbsup").toggleClass("bluecolor graycolor");
```

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends on the order the CSS is written--`bluecolor` may override `greycolor`

Answer (score 1):

Its `toggleClass` not `toggleclass`. Run the snippet below and click the link.

```js
$("#thumbsup").click(function(e){
    $("#thumbsup").toggleClass("bluecolor");
});
```

```css
.graycolor{
    color:#999;
 }
.bluecolor{
    color:#0026ff;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#" id="thumbsup" class="graycolor"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-thumbs-up"></i> Thumbs Up!</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: As I have mentioned already, it is working for plain text and not fontawesome icons

Comment: @Bharathi run the snippet. I included the fontawesome icon and it works fine...if it doesn't in your site, I would assume you have a color set somewhere for the icon that is overriding the blue color

Comment: I dont have any other override for color. Unexpectedly, the other solution to add both classes inside toggleClass worked (I am not sure why.  The code I posted was a simplified version and I am actually using jquery by "onclick" inline call in html, combining it with ajax call etc..). Anyway, thanks for your effort. I appreciate it.